# SDK sends wrong key so login fails with invalid key if facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook

I have generated keys from my debug key store as well as my release keystore and insterted them both in the "Native Android App" field for the application on facebook.

I have tested this on several devices and it always works in with the debug.keystore (when I deploy from eclipse). But when I sign the application package with my release keystore it only works if the facebook app is not installed on the device.

If facebook app is installed it sends another key which I do not recognize.

I have been very careful generating the hash key, assigning the correct path and password, as explained in the instructions from Facebook.

Note: When running with the debug.keystore it works but it seems to use the dialog auth and not the facebook app.

Thank you

```
public void share(final int score) {        
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mScoreToShare = score;

                if (mGLView != null)
                    mGLView.stopDrawing(); 

                getFacebook();

                if(!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
                    facebookAuthorize();    
                }
                else {
                    facebookShowFeedDialog();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.error("Share failed", e);

                if (mGLView != null)
                    mGLView.startDrawing();
            }
        }
    });     
}

private Facebook getFacebook() {

    if (mFacebook == null) {

        mFacebook = new Facebook("xxx");

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("xxx", MODE_PRIVATE);//getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(access_token != null) {
            mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if(expires != 0) {
            mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
    }

    return mFacebook;
}

private void facebookAuthorize() {

    //mFacebook.authorize(this, null, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {
    mFacebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("xxx", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", mFacebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", mFacebook.getAccessExpires());
            editor.commit();

            facebookShowFeedDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            mFacebook = null;
            showAlert();                
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            mFacebook = null;
            showAlert();                
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            mFacebook = null;
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }
    });     
}

private void facebookExtendAccessTokenIfNeeded() {
    if (mFacebook != null) {
        mFacebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
}

private void facebookShowFeedDialog() {

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

    String caption = "";

    parameters.putString("caption", caption);
    parameters.putString("description", "");
    parameters.putString("picture", "");

    //post on user's wall.
    mFacebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {     
            mFacebook = null;               
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            mFacebook = null;
            showAlert("");              
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            mFacebook = null;
            showAlert("");              
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            mFacebook = null;
            if (mGLView != null)
                mGLView.startDrawing();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (mFacebook != null) {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using onActivityResult? What are the logcat errors? Do you have code to show us?

Comment: It is this one: Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "xxx" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings.

Comment: Is use onActivityResult. But I only call mFacebook.authorizeCallback if mFacebook != null. I set mFacebook = null if DialogListener does not call onComplete.

Comment: You might want to check your key hash a couple of extra times. Are you sure you are copying it correctly and using the correct calls according to facebook?

Comment: Yes,I have double checked the key. Calls are correct. For example it works on a device and then I install the facebook app and it stops working.

Comment: The dialog doesnt use the hey hash, only on a device that has the facebook app if I remember correctly. So something is wrong with the key hash as the error states.

Comment: The hash key posted on facebook app settings and the hash key corresponding to the the keystore used to sign your application should always be same for SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from the facebook and create again with same hash key.